# Better phrases meaning "Learner of Android App Development"

Tags: phrase-request

I am learning Android App Development(I know how to build Android Apps to a certain extent), and since I haven't completed it, I cannot call myself an `App Developer` yet. Also, I cannot call myself an `enthusiast` or `aspirant` as these phrases doesn't describe that I could develop apps. So I decided `Learner of Android App Development` holds good. But it looks somewhat long and I need a better phrase which means the same.

I need it for LinkedIn

Comment: In what context are you wishing to employ this phrase?  On a resume?  As an introduction at a cocktail party?

Comment: @Adam the original question (which I guess was deleted) mentioned this was for a LinkedIn profile. The OP (Siddharth Venu) should probably include some such context in this new question.

Comment: If you are not yet an Android App Developer then you are a Future Android App Developer. You *could* use *aspiring* but I'd avoid it because using three words in a row starting with the same letter can sound humorous. In American English, *budding* sounds terrible in this contest, sounds like you're a tree or a boy from the 1960s.

Comment: haha ofcourse it does sound humorous. It would be weird if I put _Future Android App Developer_ na? Don't know why, it sounds weird to me

Comment: @AlanCarmack I guess Adam's answer (which I have accepted) does the job. _Novice/Intermediate Android App Developer_ sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Novice** is probably a good choice.

*Novice* is a common term used to described someone who is just beginning to learn a new set of skills.  It appears to be in the computer science world (["Novice Android Developer."](https://www.google.com/#q=%22novice%20android%20developer%22) or ["Novice Developer"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22novice+developer%22) or ["Novice Java Developer"](https://www.google.com/#q=%22novice+java+developer%22))

Novice carries the sense that you know a little about the topic and you are actively learning more.  As your skills grow, you will progress to *intermediate,* *advanced,* and hopefully *expert* status.

Comment: Thank you! That is what I was looking for. _Novice Android App Developer_... Sounds good to me. Thank you again!

Comment: I am puzzled by the downvote.    I would welcome suggestions from anyone on how to make it better.

Comment: Same here.. I'll upvote your answer once I reach 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

One word that you should consider is [budding](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/budding?q=Budding), which suggests that you do not have a lot of experience but you are "​beginning to ​develop or show ​signs of ​future ​success in a ​particular ​area".

You could therefore justify describing yourself as a **budding** Android Developer.

Comment: I'd use that but it sounds humorous in this context as @AlanCarmack said. But I guess that is also one correct way of communicating my skill level. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

> I am **training in** Android App Development. Currently I have completed ... and expect to complete my training on ...

or

> I am **studying** Android App Development.  Currently...

You could add your current skill level if you want.

Comment: I am looking for a phrase like _App Developer_ with modifications according to the skill level I have. Still, your idea seems to be a good one. Thank you :)

Comment: That isn't clear. Do you mean "experience with modifying apps"?

Comment: No. _modifications according to the skill level I have_. What I am trying to say is that I need a phrase such as App Developer, with my skill level conveyed through it. Like for eg, Begginer App Developer. And btw, I guess Adam's answer sounds good. Thank you for your help :)